# How to add a step to pandas data frame rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains time-series data from a gyroscope, sampled at 20 Hz (every 50ms).  I need to use a moving window of 4 seconds to calculate DTW distance from a reference 4 second signal.

I'm using this code:

```
df['Gyro_Z_DTW']=df['Gyro_Z'].rolling(window='4s',min_periods=80).apply(DTWDistanceWindowed,raw=False)
```

where the function *DTWDistanceWindowed()* is the following:

```
def DTWDistanceWindowed(entry):
    w=10
    s1=entry
    s2=reference

    DTW={}

    w = max(w, abs(len(s1)-len(s2)))
    print('window = ',w)

    for i in range(-1,len(s1)):
        for j in range(-1,len(s2)):
            DTW[(i, j)] = float('inf') 


    DTW[(-1, -1)] = 0

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(max(0, i-w), min(len(s2), i+w)):
            dist= (s1[i]-s2[j])**2
            DTW[(i, j)] = dist + min(DTW[(i-1, j)],DTW[(i, j-1)], DTW[(i-1, j-1)])

    return math.sqrt(DTW[len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1])

# adapted method from #http://alexminnaar.com/2014/04/16/Time-Series-Classification-and-Clustering-with-Python.html
```

It works, but I can save some time if the moving window can slide by 500 ms each time, instead of 50 ms.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm open to other suggestions rather than rolling if you know a better method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way could be to check if the first (or any index really) of `entry` is a multiple of 500ms and return `np.nan` if not. The "complex" calculation will only happen every 500ms  then. So the function would be

```
def DTWDistanceWindowed(entry):
    if bool(entry.index[0].microsecond%500000):
        return np.nan
    w=10
    s1=entry
    ....# same as your function after
```

Interestingly, [pd.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) (the type of `entry.index[0]`) has microsecond attribute but not millisecond, so `%500000` is used.

Edit: now if you want to speed up the function, you can do is using numpy array like this:

```
#sample data
np.random.seed(6)
nb = 200
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gyro_Z':np.random.random(nb)}, 
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-05-15', freq='50ms', periods=nb))
reference = np.random.random(10)

# create a for reference with your function
a = df['Gyro_Z'].rolling(window='4s',min_periods=80).apply(DTWDistanceWindowed,raw=False)
```

Define the function with numpy

```
def DTWDistanceWindowed_np(entry):
    if bool(entry.index[0].microsecond%500000):
        return np.nan
    w=10
    s1=entry.to_numpy()
    l1 = len(s1) # calcualte once the len of s1
    # definition of s2 and its length
    s2 = np.array(reference) 
    l2 = len(s2)

    w = max(w, abs(l1-l2))

    # create an array of inf and initialise
    DTW=np.full((l1+1,l2+1), np.inf)
    DTW[0, 0] = 0

    # avoid calculate some difference several times
    s1ms2 = (s1[:,None]-s2)**2
    # do the loop same way, note the small change in bounds
    for i in range(1,l1+1):
        for j in range(max(1, i-w), min(l2+1, i+w)):
            DTW[i, j] = s1ms2[i-1,j-1] + min(DTW[i-1, j],DTW[i, j-1], DTW[i-1, j-1])

    return math.sqrt(DTW[l1, l2])

# use it to create b
b = df['Gyro_Z'].rolling(window='4s',min_periods=80).apply(DTWDistanceWindowed_np,raw=False)

# compare a every 10 rows and b and mot the nan rows
print ((b.dropna() == a.dropna()[::10]).all())
# True
```

Timing:

```
#original solution
%timeit df['Gyro_Z'].rolling(window='4s',min_periods=80).apply(DTWDistanceWindowed,raw=False)
3.31 s ± 422 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# with numpy and 1 out of 10 rows
%timeit df['Gyro_Z'].rolling(window='4s',min_periods=80).apply(DTWDistanceWindowed_np,raw=False)
41.7 ms ± 9.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

so doing the `if bool(...` was already a gain of almost 10 time faster, but using `numpy` is another 9 time faster. The speed up may depends on the size of reference, I have not check this really.

Answer (score 1):

Can you resample to 500ms before applying the rolling function?

```
df['Gyro_Z'].resample('500ms').max().rolling(window='4s',min_periods=80).apply(DTWDistanceWindowed,raw=False)
```

Comment: This would clobber most of the data that the function needs to run.